# How can I add group by with ascending and decs values in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have two fields one is date and one more is function field with integer values so I wanted to add group by function field in ascending or descending order?

```
<search string="Feedback">  
    <group expand="0" string="Group By">
        <filter string="Task Name" icon="terp-personal" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'folionum'}"/>
        <filter string="Folio Number" icon="terp-personal" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'folio_number'}"/>
    </group>
</search>
```

I wanted to add a group which can get max **folio_number** comes first

Comment: What you mean with group?

Comment: I have edited my qun ?

Comment: Just change the order in the xml :)

Comment: Ordering will be done directly from listview.

Comment: yeah how to do can you please add xml tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <field name="context">{'order':'date_of asc'}</field>
```

Solved my problem

Comment: I get context field does not exist. Where do I put this?